# How to compare passwords in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a registration page and I want to compare two passwords (input fields) to be equal before writing it to a websql database.
I cannot seem to get it to work.
Any ideas?

```
function addTodo() {
var todo = document.getElementById("todo");
  var todo2 = document.getElementById("todo2");

  if(todo != todo2) {
    alert("Yours passwords do not match");
  } else {
    curatio.webdb.addTodo(todo.value);
    todo.value = "";
    alert("Your Registration was successfull");
    setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "login.html"; 
    }, 1000);
}
}


<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
            <label for="todo">
                &nbsp;Password
            </label>
            <input name="" id="todo" placeholder="" value="" type="password" required>
            </div>


            <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
            <label for="todo2">
                &nbsp;Retype your Password
            </label>
            <input name="" id="todo2" placeholder="" value="" type="password" required>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're comparing the elements instead of their values.

```
var todo = document.getElementById("todo");
var todo2 = document.getElementById("todo2");

if(todo != todo2) { // Oops
```

`todo` and `todo2` are 2 *different* `<input>` elements.

Try using `.value`:

```
if(todo.value !== todo2.value) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the actual elements, which will always be `true` (because they are both TextFields).  Compair their values, like so:

```
var todo = document.getElementById("todo").value;
var todo2 = document.getElementById("todo2").value;
```

Either this or change

```
if(todo != todo2)
```

to

```
if(todo.value != todo2.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is `Object.is(password, confirm_password)`